# Maya Python: Getting all objects in frustum with animated camera

Tags: python, maya

I'm animating a camera, and at each frame I'm trying to get the polygons in view on a sphere that the camera is aiming at. I'm creating a new Panel to do all this capturing in. However, Maya keeps capturing things from the MainWindow panel and not the new one I'm creating. Is there some kind of method I'm missing to reset focus? Also when I'm animating, `om.MGlobal.selectFromScreen` seems to stop selecting after the first frame, which seems odd.

Any help/tips here are definitely appreciated!

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel

# turn backface culling on
cmds.selectPref(useDepth=True)
cmds.selectPref(paintSelect=not(True))
mel.eval("updateHighlightSelectIcon;")

# create sphere
sphere = cmds.polySphere()[0]

# create camera and animate it around the sphere
camera = cmds.camera(
    centerOfInterest=5,
    focalLength=35,
    nearClipPlane=0.1,
    farClipPlane=10000,
    orthographic=0,
    orthographicWidth=30,
    panZoomEnabled=0,
    horizontalPan=0,
    verticalPan=0,
    zoom=1)[0]
mel.eval("objectMoveCommand")
mel.eval("cameraMakeNode 2 " + camera)
cmds.xform(camera + "_aim", t=(0,0,0))

cmds.setKeyframe(camera, t=(0,0), at="tx", v=0)
cmds.setKeyframe(camera, t=(0,0), at="tz", v=5)
cmds.setKeyframe(camera, t=(30,30), at="tx", v=5)
cmds.setKeyframe(camera, t=(30,30), at="tz", v=5)
cmds.setKeyframe(camera, t=(60,60), at="tx", v=5)
cmds.setKeyframe(camera, t=(60,60), at="tz", v=0)


# window panel setup with camera
window = cmds.window('window')
form = cmds.formLayout()
editor = cmds.modelEditor()
column = cmds.columnLayout('true')
cmds.window( window, edit=True, widthHeight=(1920, 1280) )
cmds.formLayout( form, edit=True, attachForm=[(column, 'top', 0), (column, 'left', 0), (editor, 'top', 0), (editor, 'bottom', 0), (editor, 'right', 0)], attachNone=[(column, 'bottom'), (column, 'right')], attachControl=(editor, 'left', 0, column))
cmds.modelEditor(editor, edit=True, camera=camera )
cmds.modelEditor(editor, e=True, displayAppearance="smoothShaded")
cmds.modelEditor(editor, e = True, polymeshes = True)
cmds.modelEditor(editor, e = True, xray = False)
cmds.showWindow( window )

# face mode on sphere
cmds.select(sphere, r=True)
mel.eval("SelectFacetMask")

# select all visible faces on sphere while animating the camera
for key in range(0, 60):
    cmds.currentTime(key, e=True)
    view = omu.M3dView.active3dView()
    om.MGlobal.selectFromScreen(0, 0, view.portWidth(), view.portHeight(), om.MGlobal.kReplaceList)
```